# fixing gateway on dhcp connection raspberry raspbian

Tags: linux, networking

I am using a dhcp connection which gives me everything but a gateway. I am able to do

```
sudo route add default gw 10.7.0.1 eth0
```

and get internet connection, so ping to www.google.es works just fine.

However, I want to do this automatically, so each time I restart the raspberry I get the ip address from the router and I am able to fix the gateway to gain internet access.

I've tried to write

```
gateway 10.7.0.1
```

on /etc/networks/interfaces under eth0, but this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces` and add the following line at the end `up route add default gw 10.7.0.1 eth0`....

Comment: Hi Hackerman thanks for your answer. I've tried it but I am afraid to say it doesn't work

Comment: The real problem is in your dhcp server (router?), that it doesn't provide a gateway. Have you looked at fixing that?

Comment: barny I am afraid I can't access it .

Comment: As you have provided absolutely no information about your setup no one can help. You should NOT be fiddling with `/etc/network/interfaces` in standard Raspbian.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed!

I fixed the problem just adding

```
auto eth0
```

on net `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as a unsolved Post to the community for years and saves them/us a lot of work.